# Need to EST time change to IST

Tags: jquery, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have to + 11:30 hr to the date `(3/23/2020 12:46:00 AM)`. Then date format will be MM/DD/YYYY

Ex: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2b8mj.png) used forma in excel =Text(date+"11:30:00","MM/DD/YYYY")

How this will do in IIF condition in MS Access?

Comment: I don't understand what you need and want, I am sure others don't too, please explain better. It is easy to add time/days/mouth/year to date with js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean to *add* 11:30 to the *date* of that date/time value in Access, it could be:

```
NewDateTime = Int(OldDateTime) + #11:30:00#
```

Comment: Hi Gustav i tried the above code it seams a error kindly check and help me. please see the formula below i used for your reference.  Int([CoderCompletedTime2]+11:30:00)